# In ubuntu 22.04 custom kernels not booting up on dell Pc

Tags: boot

I have did kernel compilation and tried to bootup the system with customised kernel in Dell pc but it is not coming up.

Solutions tried

1. Disable secure BIOS.
2. Updated Grub parameters.
3. Updated the BIOS.

Comment: It is unclear what kernels you are trying to boot. How did you install them? What do you mean by " it is not coming up"?

Comment: Kernels means the newer versions of linux kernels like  6.1.0 , 6.1.8 . The version is taken from kernel.org and compiled it in the PC . After compilation the pc is not booting up with newer versions as mentioned above. It is getting stuck at " loading 6.1.8 , loading initial ramdisk".